# Color gradient inside an edge

Tags: python, networkx

I'm modelling a gas network with networkx and I would like to visualize the pressure drop inside the pipes (edges). We made the assumption that the pressure drops in a linear way from the pressure at node 1 to the pressure at node 2. I would like to add a color gradient to represent the pressure decrease inside the pipes.

How can I set the edge color in order to have this color gradient corresponding to the 'local' pressure?

I already know how to set a color corresponding to an attribute, but I'm stuck with this gradient. 
I tried the Line collection but couldn't go further with it.